# How to install gitolite on Ubuntu 10.10 server?

Tags: 10.10, server, git

I am trying to install gitolite on an ubuntu 10.10 server. It seems from the google that gitolite should have a package in the repos, but I dont see any install candidates on my box. I can grab the source from github, but not entirely sure how to install that...

any help on how to get gitolite installed?

Answer (score 1):

gitolite is [in the repos](http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/gitolite). Check if you have this line in your /etc/apt/sources.list file:

> deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-security main universe

If you don't have, add it. If you already have but commented, just remove the `#` character in front of the line.

After that you can update your repos and install gitolite.